# SharePoint online add link to a document library on new list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience

starting to use SharePoint online and I am loving it so far.  However I need some guidance (if anyone can guide me by giving me material where to look at).

Basically I want to modify the ItemAdded and ItemEdited process to inject some extra work that needs to be done in a custom list. Scenario is, when I create a new list item, I want to create a document library and on the newly created list item add a link to the newly created document library.

I was wondering if this can be achieved using javascript and jquery.

Comment: Are you using Modern or classic experience?

Comment: Modern Experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as CarIF said, you can use flow to send HTTP request and create a new library through Rest API. Please check this:https://www.fidelityfactory.com/blog/2019/3/15/using-the-powerful-sharepoint-http-action-in-ms-flow-to-create-modern-libraries

And then you can use an update list item action to add the link to the list item.

Comment: Thanks.  Very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Microsoft Flow? You can add a custom action whenever an item is added to a list. Some of the options are to create a SharePoint folder, file, or item, and to create a sharing link. If a folder will suit your needs instead of a new library, you can do it without coding at all.

The process might be to open the list in SharePoint, then click the Flow menu >> Create a Flow >> Show More >> When a new item is added in SharePoint, complete a custom action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using JS/PreSaveItem and REST or perhaps SPservices.  You really want to create a whole new library?  so that with REST services.  adding a list back to the list for the newly created library is easy since you know the link when you create the doc lib via it's name   /site/doclibname  will do it.